# ArcGis Server Object Extension Development

Tags: arcgis

I'm a newbie in ArcGis and I'd like to start with creating a simple extension for our ArcGis Server.

My environment:

1. Remote ArcGis server 10.3.
2. ArcGis client 10.3.
3. MS Visual studio 2013.
4. ArcObjects SDK for NET Framework 10.3.
5. ArcGIS Runtime SDK DotNet 100_2_1.

For creating a project I used an ArcGis/Server Object Extensions/REST template.
So that basic code was generated automatically. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to build the solution, I get an error:

> "1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ESRI\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.Server.11.targets(49,5): error : The target location must be an existing file!"

Actually the file ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.Server.11.targets contains references to an assembly:

> `AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="PackageAddIn" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '12.0'`

Could anyone tell me please how to solve this and get a soe-file after building?

Thanks in advance!